# converting the fzero function of MATLAB (Brent Method) to C code

Tags: c, matlab

I am trying to write a similar function in C to the one in MATLAB called `fzero`, I found out that fzero uses the Brent method in order to find roots.

```
T=fzero(MyFunction,CATHRESHOLD);
```

this is the function I need, it is suppose to give me the zero of MyFunction near `CATHRESHOLD`.

When I tried to implement the Brent method in order to find the required result I figured out that in addition to MyFunction I need two inputs `a` and `b`.

`b` is considered as the current guess for the root of MyFunction.
`a` is a point such that `MyFunction(a)` and `MyFunction(b)` have opposite signs, so the interval `[a, b]` contains the solution.

I can write a C code of the brent method knowing all the inputs but I couldn't write one knowing only the function, and what I called `CATHRESHOLD`.
How should I choose the value of `a` ?!

could anyone explains to me how `fzero` works maybe that would help!

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) of `fzero(fun,x0)`, you can see that `x0` should be *within* the interval `[a,b]` such that `f(a)` and `f(b)` have different signs.

By typing `edit fzero` in the command window, we can open the function itself. This may help you write your own version, by looking through the non-obfuscated code. At the top of the function we see the description:

```matlab
%   X = FZERO(FUN,X0) tries to find a zero of the function FUN near X0, 
%   if X0 is a scalar.  It first finds an interval containing X0 where the 
%   function values of the interval endpoints differ in sign, then searches 
%   that interval for a zero.
```

So `fzero` still uses an interval `[a,b]`, it just finds that interval surrounding the scalar `X0`. Note you can also pass the interval to `fzero`, as detailed by the second input option:

```matlab
%   X = FZERO(FUN,X0), where X0 is a vector of length 2, assumes X0 is a 
%   finite interval where the sign of FUN(X0(1)) differs from the sign of 
%   FUN(X0(2)). An error occurs if this is not true.
```

---

Specifically, see the part of the function which begins

```matlab
% Interval input
```

Where we see the processing of the two above input options

```matlab
if (numel(x) == 2) 
    % ...
    a = x(1); savea=a;
    b = x(2); saveb=b;
    % ... 
elseif (numel(x) == 1)
    % ...
    % method for calculating a and b
    % ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do this in C and test against fzero.  The biggest help was from Mathworks founder and one of Brent's advisors in the early 70's, Cleve Moler.

The best fzero reference is in netlib ([as stated in this article](https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2015/11/09/zeroin-part-3-matlab-zero-finder-fzero/?s_tid=blogs_rc_3)) written in FORTRAN. Essentially what's in Brent's 1971 paper (written in ALGOR 60).  The psuedo-code on Wikipedia does not work (there's a warning banner about it) — I have confirmed that.